# How to iterate through this matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, syntax, matrix, dimensions

I'm new to matlab and I'm trying to do the following:

```
For each x in [L, a, and b] :
TxP = tx_ * ratio_x;
```

where I have a matrix with dimensions L,a,b and the 'x' part of tx_ refers to the dimension L, a, or b.

I'm just unsure of the syntax to make this happen. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have a look at the MATLAB documentation for for loops: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html
You will probably need to use nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of your question (I would add a comment, but I don't have the reputation sorry). Could you please clarify?

If ratio_x is a matrix of the same dimension (L, a, b), you would not want to use a loop in MATLAB, you want to do element-wise multiplication of the matrices:

```
TxP = tx_ .* ratio_x;
```